# Definition of the differential of a function

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

I have been reading some differential geometry from the book " An Introduction to Manifolds" by Tu and so far i like how he exposes the topic. Now i got to the part where he defines Differential forms in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and i understood the definition but then he defines the differential of a $C^{\infty}$ function, that its going to be a 1-form, and i am confused with is notation.

He writes $(df)_p(X_p)=X_pf$ and i dont quite understand what is going on in the last term , how is that going to be a tangent vector to the point $p$, i guess im having some trouble with the notation. Is the function calculated at some point?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that $X_pf$ is the directional derivative of $f$ at $p$ in the direction of $X_p$. Remember from basic calculus that (for $C^1$ functions in Euclidean space) the directional derivative is the dot product $\nabla f(p)\cdot X_p$. The one-form $df$ gives exactly this computation: $df(p)(X_p)$ is likewise that directional derivative.

Comment: Ah yes that makes alot of sense , Thank you man !!!

Comment: You're most welcome. Check out some of my YouTube lectures on differential forms and manifolds, linked in my profile. Much of the material will be easy for you, but some may be helpful. Have fun!

Comment: Will do , Thanks !!